# When using jenkins to build a project, use git pull in the exceute shell,i get

Tags: git, jenkins

When using jenkins to build a project, use git pull in the exceute shell,I get the following error:

```
+ git pull
Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

I don't know How to configure git ssh in jenkins.

Comment: Please provide more information on this. Show your job configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my answer I expect authentication to git to be done with [SSH keys](https://help.github.com/articles/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/).

The preferred way to use git in Jenkins is to set it up in the Configuration -> Source Code Management.

Should this not fit your workflow, and you want to use git commands from the shell, you should install the [SSH agent plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/SSH+Agent+Plugin). You should set up the SSH key under Configuration -> Build Environment -> SSH agent. All steps in your build will be executed with this SSH key available, so pulling and pushing to git should become possible.

Comment: You can achieved the same without SSH agent plugin, just use the jenkins user to create and manipulate ssh keys, then run a shell command that required the ssh keys..

Comment: Thinks @Joep Weijers, According to your method I solved the problem.